# Grab multiple radio values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a section with a lot of blocks (I'll use only two on this example). The situation is: I have a `<div>` with a `<input>`, a `<select>` group and `<radio>` buttons. After filling all of them and clicking on "Grab" button, the script will show an alert with this values.

But if you fill more then one block, the last one doesn't grab the radios. It always returns `"undefined"`. If you leave the first blocks with empty radios and fill the last one, the info on the alert screen will show the last one, however it's wrong.

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5sVA/1/)

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contentArray = '';

    $('button').click(function() { 
        $('.option_group').each(function(i) { 
            var NotEmptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value !== ""; });
            var NotEmptyCombo = $('option:selected').filter(function() { return this.text !== ""; });       

            NotEmptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
                name = this.name;
                val = this.value;                       
                var combo = $('#c_'+name).val();                    
                var radio = $('input[name=r_'+name+']:checked', '#theform').val();
                contentArray = contentArray+name+'='+"'"+val+"'"+","+"'"+combo+"'"+","+radio+";"+"|";   
                radio = '';
            });

            alert(contentArray);    
            contentArray = '';

            return false;
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id ="theform">
    <div class="option_group" id="bloco">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Cargo" name="cargo" id="carga"/>
        <select class="filtercombo" id="c_cargo">
            <option>like</option>
            <option>=</option>
            <option>!=</option>
            <option><</option>
            <option><=</option>
            <option>></option>
            <option>>=</option>
            <option>is null</option>
            <option>is not null</option>
            <option>in</option>
            <option>not in</option>
            <option>between</option>
            <option>contains</option>
            <option>not like</option>
        </select>

        <input type="radio" value="up" name="r_cargo">
        <input type="radio" value="down" name="r_cargo">
        <input type="radio" value="flat" name="r_cargo">
    </div><!-- @end of option_group -->

    <div class="option_group" id="bloco">   
        <input type="text" placeholder="provider" name="provider" id="provider"/>
        <select class="filtercombo" id="c_provider">
            <option>like</option>
            <option>=</option>
            <option>!=</option>
            <option><</option>
            <option><=</option>
            <option>></option>
            <option>>=</option>
            <option>is null</option>
            <option>is not null</option>
            <option>in</option>
            <option>not in</option>
            <option>between</option>
            <option>contains</option>
            <option>not like</option>
        </select>

        <input type="radio" value="up" name="r_provider1" />
        <input type="radio" value="down" name="r_provider2" />
        <input type="radio" value="flat" name="r_provider3" />  
    </div><!-- @end of option_group -->

    <button type="button">grab</button> 

</form>
```

Comment: Are you aware that you have two `<div>` tags with the same `id`?

Comment: This will be generated dynamically later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different names for your last group of radios `r_provider1, r_provider2, r_provider3`, they should all have the same name 'r_provider'.